# Where does my web server serve files from?

Tags: arch-linux, webserver

I want to put files on my Arch Linux file server so that others can download them via HTTP. Where under `/var` should they be placed?

Comment: Did you have any particular idea about how you wanted others to download them?

Comment: Well I'm currently using DynDns.org

Comment: That does not come anywhere near to answering my question.

Comment: By using Dyndns.org I a have a URL (My Server name).dyndns.org. This URL is how others would download my files.

Comment: So then did you mean your answer to be "Via a web server running on my machine"?

Comment: Yes, I have used a server set up this way before, but I cannot remember how I put files on it. I was thinking is was in a subfolder in /var

Comment: Please note the differences between the original and the corrected version.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly it's /var/www but it depends on your webserver and the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check what web server software you have installed. The default on most
   distros will be apache, but again like most distributions ArchLinux also supplies `lighttpd` and `nginx` so it depends on which one you picked.
2. Check the config files of the installed server software. This will likely be in `/etc/<softwarename>/`, so `/etc/apache/` or `/etc/nginx` or `/etc/lighttpd` depending on 1).
3. Somewhere in said configuration there will be a header stating the default document root for the default host. As @Rainer pointed out, `/var/www` is the most commonly used standard location, but it never hurts to make sure. Homework for this step: [Lighttpd docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lighttpd), [NginX docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nginx), [Apache docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache) depending on which software you installed
4. ...
5. Profit!

Comment: I don't mind being downvoted, but if whoever did so would please leave some constructive criticism as to why my answer was inaccurate, poorly worded or factually incorrect I'd appreciate it.